# Unable to configure oracle 11g net server

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I installed Oracle 11g on my Windows Server 2008 workstation. After I try to configure oracle net server with port number 1521. But ONS error say to me as "Use another port number. This port is already in use.". How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [www.sysinternals.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-za/sysinternals) - download the Sysinternals suite - and then run Tcpview and check what executable is running on port 1521. You can sort by port by clicking on the "Local port" column. If you try and run `netstat -abn` from the command line, you'll (in all likelihood) get an error "The requested operation requires an elevation". Just why this error occurs when this information is available through Tcpview is a mystery.

Do you have an Oracle instance already installed? I've installed Oracle on a number of Windows machines and I've never come across port 1521 being used by anything else. In any case, Tcpview will tell you which executable is blocking your Oracle port.

[EDIT - after further research]

I was reading around this and I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23718720/470530), which shows that running resmon.exe will give you the information htat you want - Go to the "Listening Ports" tab, "Ports" column, but as pointed out, the GUI is truly awful.

From the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48207/470530), from the command line you can run netstat -aon | find /i "listening"``, but as I mention, I can't get the corresponding process name using the `b` flag.

Comment: TNSLSNR.EXE is runing on 1521 and I have installed oracle instance, But now it deleted and clear all net service, now i want create from begin

Comment: Uninstall everything to do with Oracle - it appears to me that there was some attempt made at a previous install. If you can, I would even reinstall Windows from scratch. But, at least make sure **absolutely** everything Oracle is uninstalled - and then reinstall from scratch. It's not normal for you to get the error message that you did.

Comment: Thanx you for advice